# when use synchronized to lock write, if need volatile to guard to avoid the read old value or not full value?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, synchronized

as titled. I have use synchronized to guard multi-thread write. but I want know if I need add volatile to guard read . (as we know,  I can use synchronized to guard read too, but it will prevent read and write concorrently. what' more ,if I use reentraent lock. it will prevent too.)

```
private volatile BigDecimal cacheMiss = BigDecimal.ZERO;

public  BigDecimal getCacheHit() {
    return cacheHit;
}

public void increaseCacheMiss() {
    synchronized (cacheMissLock) {
        this.cacheMiss = this.cacheMiss.add(STEP);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't expect to track more than 2 billion cache hits you can use Java 5's [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) without doing any of your own synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cacheMiss` can be updated from several threads, then it needs to be declared `volatile` if you absolutely need to read the latest value. Otherwise a thread may be reading a thread-local value (stashed in a register or core cache), not bothering to go out to main memory to see the latest value.

Comment: Thanks. but I want to know why I need add volatile. Some books mention: synchonized also guard visibility. So why I still need volatile to guard visibility?

Comment: @jiafu - If all your accesses are in `synchronized` blocks, then you don't need to declare it `volatile`. But in your sample code you have a read that is outside a `synchronzed` block. There's an excellent article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html) that explores this issue.

Comment: I catch your mean. Thanks . but I have another question. if synchronized can prevent code reoder in the inner of guard code. I query the quesion in this website. Somebody say it can't prevent the reoder in inner of guard code of synchronized code. What's more , some books mention that: volatile can diable reorder aroud the field. So what's your opinion?

Comment: according to some books and my understand. I think synchronized only prevent reoder between synchronized code chunk and other synchronized code. but volatile can prevent the code reoder around other code. Am I right?

Comment: @jiafu - `volatile` can indeed prevent reordering. Within a `synchronized` block, reordering is not a problem because (with proper synchronization) only the thread holding the lock can be accessing the variable. (Reordering used to be a problem with writing thread-safe singletons--see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html)--but much of that was fixed as of Java 5, without using `volatile`.)

Comment: My thought is:  if use synchonized { object read=new demo(). }, but other thread read (getObject(return read)) without synchorized and volatile . if I can get the object on the error state such as initial half of process? if synchorized can't prevent reorder in inner code. object can be referenced at first and be assgined latter. So i can watch the error state. Many thanks to you. This problem always puzzle me.

Comment: @jiafu - The article I linked to in my last comment has links to other articles that explain the Java memory model in depth. There's far more to this subject than can be covered in a comment (or even an answer) here. Good luck.

Comment: 3ks, I will read it carefully. Many thanks for your warm answers.